# why does not the Internet require a single routing protocol for all stand-alone systems?

Tags: routing

why we are not using one routing protocol like OSPF for example for all autonumus systems.

Comment: Because different protocols do different things, required for different scenarios.

Comment: Because they're autonomous.  That means they make their own decisions about how to operate their networks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

To be blunt, in *my* network, *I* will run whatever *I* want; nobody outside my network has any say in it. When my network connects to someone else's network, we have to come to an agreement. For decades now, The Internet™ has agreed on BGP as the inter-AS routing protocol.

(You might find a few odd locales using IS-IS, but that's still a local agreement.)

Answer (score 4):

I could give you a very thorough long-winded explanation that you may/may-not understand... Instead I will say the following:

- Scalability:  OSPF, EIGRP, and other routing protocols do not scale to levels needed efficiently, only BGP does this.
- Control: No routing protocol offers more means of manipulation than BGP.
- Security: Protocols like OSPF running globally across the internet would introduce significant security risks.

That's just a few reasons.